# Word guessing game -- Can this be written any better?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is just a portion of the game, a function that takes in the secret word and the letters guessed as arguments and tells you if they guessed the word correctly.

I'll be completely honest, this is from an assignment on an edX course, **however** I have already passed this assignment, this code works. I am just wondering if it can be written any better. Some people in the discussion forums were talking about how they solved it with 1 line, which is why I'm asking.

```py
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    guessed = []
    l= str(lettersGuessed)
    s= list(secretWord)
    for i in l:
        if i in s:
            guessed.append(i)
            guessed.sort()
            s.sort()
    return guessed == s
```

Here is one of the test cases from the grader as an example:

`isWordGuessed('durian', ['h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'm', 'n', 'r', 't', 'u'])`

Comment: If this question is solely about code improvement, I suggest it be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com instead. You state the code is working, so there's nothing to "solve," here, outside of improvements to existing, working code.

Comment: @not_a_robot While [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) might be a good place to suggest going for this type of question, we should get out of the habit of sending question-askers over there. Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.

Comment: Hadn't seen that, thanks. I see it either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this is pretty short:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
  return all([c in lettersGuessed for c in secretWord])
```

For every character in the `secretWord` ensure it's in the `lettersGuessed`. This basically creates a list of booleans and the built-in [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if every element in the array is `True`.

Also, FWIW: Idiomatic python would use underscores and not camel case.

Comment: Oh I see, that's a great solution. I tried doing it this way using all but my code wasn't passing. I guess I was just using all wrong. I was using `all(x == lettersGuessed for x in secretWord)` because I'm still a beginner and that's the only way I know how to use all. Thanks for the lesson!  -- Also, I usually use underscores as well, but I'm just using the function names, arguments and variables given in the assignment description to avoid confusion.